# How to get average value from a column in a database through C# in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

I'm very new to C# and working in ASP.NET, and I'm supposed to get all the information from a   table in a local database that I have connected with in Visual Studio. All I really know is how to connect and how to get the whole table in a grid view, but I would in the end of the grid view, or maybe in some other way to show the medium value for each column.

It's the answers from a survey built on radiobuttons with the values 1 to 5. So I want to get the medium from each question. In my database I only have one column for id and one column each for every question.

Right now I have this:

The code in result.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdResult" CssClass="grid" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

The code in result.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Uppgift_3
{
 public partial class result : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (resultatEntities datakoppling = new resultatEntities()) 
        {
            var answers = from survey in datakoppling.surveyAnswers
                          select survey;

            grdResult.DataSource = answers;

            grdResult.DataBind();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

When i put things in to the database in default.aspx:

```
    protected void saveSurvey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (resultatEntities datakoppling = new resultatEntities())
        {

            var saveSurvey = new surveyAnswers();

            saveSurvey.Question1 = RadioButtonQuestion1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            saveSurvey.Question2 = RadioButtonQuestion2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            saveSurvey.Question3 = RadioButtonQuestion3.SelectedItem.ToString();
            saveSurvey.Question4 = RadioButtonQuestion4.SelectedItem.ToString();
            saveSurvey.Question5 = RadioButtonQuestion5.SelectedItem.ToString();
            saveSurvey.Question6 = RadioButtonQuestion6.SelectedItem.ToString();
            saveSurvey.Question7 = RadioButtonQuestion7.SelectedItem.ToString();
            saveSurvey.Question8 = RadioButtonQuestion8.SelectedItem.ToString();
            saveSurvey.Question9 = RadioButtonQuestion9.SelectedItem.ToString();
            saveSurvey.Question10 = RadioButtonQuestion10.SelectedItem.ToString();

            datakoppling.surveyAnswers.AddObject(saveSurvey);
            datakoppling.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Medium? Do you mean median?

Comment: Do you mean the [average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average) value?

Comment: Im sry its my english.. I wasn't sure what you call it in english. But i mean the average! =) If you translated what i wrote to swedish it sounds good ^^ hehe.

Comment: Could you post the `surveyAnswer` class structure?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you want the ***mean*** value (or average), that's pretty easy:

```
var mean = datakoppling.surveyAnswers.Average(s => s.Value);
```

If you mean that you want the ***median*** value (the value such that half of the values in the set are above and half of the values in the set are below), it takes a bit more work, but you can still do it. Try this:

```
var count = datakoppling.surveyAnswers.Count();
var midPoint = count / 2;
double medianValue;
if (count % 2 = 0)
{
    medianValue = datakoppling.surveyAnswers
                              .OrderBy(s => s.Value)
                              .Take(midPoint + 1)
                              .Skip(midPoint - 1)
                              .Average(s => s.Value);
}
else
{
    medianValue = datakoppling.surveyAnswers
                              .OrderBy(s => s.Value)
                              .Select(s => s.Value)
                              .Take(midPoint + 1)
                              .Last();
}
```

Here I assumed the property `Value` was what you want to average, of course you can tweak this code as needed to fit your particular case.

---

**Update**:
As a side note, you can calculate multiple averages with a single query like this:

```
var averages = 
    from s in datakoppling.surveyAnswers
    group s by 0 into g
    select new 
    {
        Value1 = g.Average(s => s.Value1),
        Value2 = g.Average(s => s.Value2),
        Value3 = g.Average(s => s.Value3),
        ...
    };
```

To use this to DataBind to your grid, simply do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (resultatEntities datakoppling = new resultatEntities()) 
    {
        var averages = 
            from s in datakoppling.surveyAnswers
            group s by 0 into g
            select new 
            {
                question1 = g.Average(s => s.question1),
                question2 = g.Average(s => s.question2),
                question3 = g.Average(s => s.question3),
                ...
            };

        grdResult.DataSource = averages;

        grdResult.DataBind();
    }
}
```

If you want *both* the answers and the averages in the grid use:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (resultatEntities datakoppling = new resultatEntities()) 
    {
        var answers = 
            from s in datakoppling.surveyAnswers
            select new 
            {
                id = s.Id,
                question1 = (double)s.question1,
                question2 = (double)s.question2,
                question3 = (double)s.question3,
                ...
            };
        var averages = 
            from s in datakoppling.surveyAnswers
            group s by 0 into g
            select 
            {
                id = 0,
                question1 = g.Average(s => s.question1),
                question2 = g.Average(s => s.question2),
                question3 = g.Average(s => s.question3),
                ...
            };

        grdResult.DataSource = answers.Union(averages);

        grdResult.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I only mean the average, but for each column in the database, not the hole database? :)

Comment: I tried the first code, but it say's that survey dosent exist, what is supposed to be there? Then i can figure it out what I named it =)

Comment: @SannaBergström Sorry, there was a bug in my original code. See my updated answer. The first example shows how to get the average of a single column. You can simply repeat as necessary to get the average value for other columns.

Comment: No problem, nice that you're trying to help! Now its complaining about the part value.. maybe have something to do with that in my database I have varchar?

Comment: @SannaBergström yes you cannot average a VARCHAR. It needs to be a numerical type first. Also, the name `Value` was just my stand-in for whatever the actual property you wanted to average. If you post the structure of `surveyAnswers` we may be able to help you out more.

Comment: Ok! the structure is that there are 11 colums, 1 is called id and are the primary key, whit an "auto increment" and the other columns is called question1, question2 and so on. They are varchar(50) and no column are allowed to have nulls. The database is in sql server.

Comment: So the values in the database are numbers but of course in strings. That was only because i didn't know how to make the rest of the code.. Im studing and learning this and the rest i lerned from a lecture ^^.

Comment: @SannaBergström Unless you need to have them as strings, I suggest you turn `question1`..`question10` into INT or DECIMAL columns. It will make your life a lot easier in the future. However, you can still work with VARCHAR's by parsing them first using `.Average(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.question1))`, etc.

Comment: Ok.. but then I dont know how to solve the rest of the code.. when i put it in the database! ^^ if you maybe cna help me with that as well? I added that code in the question above! And i get the "answers" throu radiobutton lists

Comment: @SannaBergström To store get selected value as an integer use this `int.Parse(RadioButtonQuestion1.SelectedValue)` or `Convert.ToInt32(s.RadioButtonQuestion1.SelectedValue))`

Comment: I tried Convert.ToInt32(s.question1)); .. It dosent work.. it says = "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: I triede int.parse and it dosent work and i tried Convert.ToInt32.. it complains about s not existing...?

Comment: @SannaBergström Oops that should be `Convert.ToInt32(RadioButtonQuestion1.SelectedValue)`. but if you have already changed your table to use INT's you don't need to call `Convert(s.question1))` to get your average, just `.Average(s => s.question1)` will do.

Comment: it dosent work like that eighter.. And yes now I change in the database!

Comment: I tried to write saveSurvey.Question1 = RadioButtonQuestion1.SelectedValue; And that seams to work, but there is a problem in result.aspx.cs wiht databind.. the error message says that The 'Question1' property on 'surveyAnswers' could not be set to a 'Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'String'.

Comment: At select in result.aspx.cs it says=   Error 6 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Uppgift_3.surveyAnswers>' to 'int'

Comment: Please help me fast.. I need to get this assaignment done before 23.59! Now im starting to feel stressed =(

Comment: @SannaBergström I'm sorry, I'm not sure how else to help you. The code should work as posted. You asked for how to do this through C# and my answer does that. For DataBinding to a grid, try using my last code snippet.

Comment: But now i havent event got to getting the average.. first i want to list it all.. And that dosent work now!!!!! So how do i program that? First..             using (resultatEntities datakoppling = new resultatEntities()) 
            {

                var answers = from survey in datakoppling.surveyAnswers
                              select survey;

                grdResult.DataSource = answers;

                grdResult.DataBind();



            
            }

Comment: That is where the problem is first.. because it cant make it to int.. but it should already be int in the database so i dont understand it???

Comment: @SannaBergström I'm if you're saying your problem is in saving the data to the database  or retrieving it back to from the database. If the data is an INT in the database my code works, and for databinding to a grid, my last code sample works. If the problem is in saving it to the database, the code in my comments should be fine. If you are having other issues, it's probably outside the scope of this question, I recommend opening a new question which details the new problem (and don't say, 'help I have a deadline' -- that'll just get you down-voted)

Comment: But Im saying, there is no problem saving it anymore!!!!!!!! The problem is selecting ti from the database... That is the part that dosent work now!

Comment: @SannaBergström I've added the exact code you need to use. see my updated answer.

Comment: I tried your update code, just copied it right of and filled in whit the rest of the "questions".. It still errors, now the error is about "s.Question1" (and all the others) it says that it cant convert string to decimal.. =(

Comment: @SannaBergström Then you haven't converted the columns to to a numeric type. Both your entity model *and* your database have to be updated.

Comment: But I have droped the table and created it again white int.. thats why i dont get whats wrong?

Comment: @SannaBergström You probably didn't [update your entity model](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/08/entity-framework-manual-update.html#.Uau0aUDrx3M).

Comment: Acctually your totaly right, I updated it now and now it seem to work with Convert.ToInt32(RadioButtonQuestion1.SelectedValue).. But another error in the result.aspx.cs side.. it complaines about: g.Average(s => s.Question1), (and all the others) It says that "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exist(are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @SannaBergström I assume you're using my last code snippet. You could do `(int)g.Average(s => s.Question1)` but that will truncate the answer (rounding down to the nearest integer). I've provided an update which should work without truncating.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I had to get it in so I had to leve out the average part.. To bad =/ Now im to tired to try the last thing you said, but maybe later ^^.

Comment: @SannaBergström No problem, happy coding. And don't forget, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted for the benefit of future visitors.